# php echo span style color based on content

Tags: html, styles, echo

Stucked with somehting and i need your help on this.

For below image:

[image]

if a contact have one of the **client_contact_type** labeled either as Owner,Apporval or Manager the span style echo text should show green and for anything else should be red

```
 `<span style="color:<?php echo ($client_contact_type=="Owner"?"green":"red");?>;`
```

on this code, i could only put one label, dont know how to put multiple

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the or operators:

```php
echo ($client_contact_type=="Owner" || $client_contact_type=="Approval" || $client_contact_type=="Manager") ? "green" : "red";
```

Or use the in_array function:

```php
echo in_array($client_contact_type, ["Owner", "Approval", "Manager"]) ? "green" : "red"
```